How do I correctly get/project the 2D position of a 3D point that behind a camera?
I have written a software renderer using SDL2's rendergeometry which works completely fine up until the point where I have to get the 2D position of a 3D point, this code works fine but the moment a 3D point is behind the camera the result gets "corrupted" and the triangles are drawn incorrectly.
no triangle points behind camera
camera moved forward
From my understanding, the code I should have should transform the points correctly when they go behind the camera, but it does not appear to be doing this.
intended result
//vecAngleTo
double vecAngleTo(FVector3 a, FVector3 v) {
    return acos((a | v) / a.Length() / v.Length());
}

//3D projection code.
SDL_FPoint positionOnScreen(const FVector3 &point) {
    //Calculate the line from the camera to the vector
    Line lineToVector = Line(Camera::position, point - Camera::position);

    FVector3 s = cameraPlane.position; //A point on the plane
    FVector3 n = cameraPlane.direction; //The normal vector of the plane
    FVector3 p = lineToVector.position; //A point on the line
    FVector3 v = lineToVector.direction; //The direction vector of the line

    //some even more shorteners. the pipe operator here is used as dot product
    float sumNV = (n | v);
    float sumSN = (s | n);

    //the equation
    float t = (sumSN - (n | p)) / sumNV;
    if(t < 0.f) {
        //it's behind the camera, now what to do here?
    }

    //have the position
    FVector3 positionOnPlane = p + v * t;

    //Calculate the vector from the bottom-left corner of the camera plane to the intersection point
    FVector3 fromBottomLeftToPositionOnPlane = positionOnPlane - cameraPlaneBottomLeft;

    //Calculate the angles between the camera plane vectors and the vector to the intersection point
    float angleToWidth = vecAngleTo(cameraPlaneWidth, fromBottomLeftToPositionOnPlane);
    float angleToHeight = vecAngleTo(cameraPlaneHeight, fromBottomLeftToPositionOnPlane);

    //Return a SDL_FPoint containing the coordinates.
    return {
        cos(angleToWidth) * fromBottomLeftToPositionOnPlane.Length() / cameraPlaneWidth.Length() * RENDERWIDTH,
        RENDERHEIGHT - (cos(angleToHeight) * fromBottomLeftToPositionOnPlane.Length() / cameraPlaneHeight.Length() * RENDERHEIGHT)
    };
}

I have my planes set up in this form:
#define RENDERWIDTH 320
#define RENDERHEIGHT 240
#define NEARDISTANCE 0.01f

//Line class
class Line {
public:
    FVector3 position, direction;
    Line() {}
    Line(FVector3 p, FVector3 d) : position(p), direction(d) {}
};

//Plane class
class Plane {
public:
    FVector3 position, direction;
    Plane() {}
    Plane(FVector3 p, FVector3 d) : position(p), direction(d) {}
    Plane(FVector3 a, FVector3 b, FVector3 c) : position(a), direction((a - b)^(c - b)) {}

    //Distance from vector.
    float distanceFrom(const FVector3 &v) const {
        FVector3 vec = v - position;
        return (direction | vec) / direction.Length();
    }
};

bool isOnScreen(const Primitive *t) {
    //this is the good check but it leads to corruption
    return isInFrontOfCamera(t->P1) || isInFrontOfCamera(t->P2) || isInFrontOfCamera(t->P3);
    //return true;
    //a Primitive is considered to be on screen if every FVector3 that it has is in front of the camera and
    //  at least one FVector3 is on the screen
    //return (isInFrontOfCamera(t->P1) && isInFrontOfCamera(t->P2) && isInFrontOfCamera(t->P3)) && (isOnScreen(t->P1) || isOnScreen(t->P2) || isOnScreen(t->P3));
}


    //Initialize the camera planes and vectors.
    cameraPlane = Plane(Camera::position + Camera::lookDirection.Unit() * NEARDISTANCE, Camera::lookDirection);

    Camera::rightDirection = Camera::upDirection ^ (Camera::lookDirection);

    //Length() is the magnitude.
    cameraPlaneWidth = Camera::rightDirection.Unit() * (sin(deg2rad(Camera::FOV / 2)) / sin(deg2rad(90 - Camera::FOV / 2))) * NEARDISTANCE * 2;
    cameraPlaneHeight = Camera::upDirection.Unit() * cameraPlaneWidth.Length() / RENDERWIDTH * RENDERHEIGHT;
    cameraPlaneBottomLeft = cameraPlane.position - (cameraPlaneWidth / 2) - (cameraPlaneHeight / 2);

    cameraBottomPlane = Plane(Camera::position, cameraPlaneBottomLeft + cameraPlaneWidth, cameraPlaneBottomLeft);
    cameraTopPlane = Plane(Camera::position, cameraPlaneBottomLeft + cameraPlaneHeight, cameraPlaneBottomLeft + cameraPlaneHeight + cameraPlaneWidth);
    cameraRightPlane = Plane(Camera::position, cameraPlaneBottomLeft + cameraPlaneWidth + cameraPlaneHeight, cameraPlaneBottomLeft + cameraPlaneWidth);
    cameraLeftPlane = Plane(Camera::position, cameraPlaneBottomLeft, cameraPlaneBottomLeft + cameraPlaneHeight);
    //Render all the primitives.
    for(Primitive *t : primitivesToRender) {
        if(isOnScreen(t)) {
            //Position
            verts[0].position = positionOnScreen(t->P1);
            verts[1].position = positionOnScreen(t->P2);
            verts[2].position = positionOnScreen(t->P3);

            //Colors
            SDL_Color finalcolor = computeColor(t->color, t->getDirection()); //just do t->color if no smart coloring required.
            verts[0].color = finalcolor;
            verts[1].color = finalcolor;
            verts[2].color = finalcolor;

            //Texcoords
            if(t->Texture) {
                verts[0].tex_coord = t->T1;
                verts[1].tex_coord = t->T2;
                verts[2].tex_coord = t->T3;
            }
            SDL_RenderGeometry(ren, t->Texture, &verts[0], 3, nullptr, 0 );
        }
    }

I have tried returning invalid coordinates or offscreen when the point is behind the camera, but I haven't found a way to properly project the points, which leads to the results looking wrong.
    //the equation
    float t = (sumSN - (n | p)) / sumNV;
    if(t < 0.f) {
        return {-512.f, -512.f}; //wrong
    }

